# How to plot a titration curve in R?

Tags: r, plot, chemistry

I  would like to plot a smooth titration curve with empirical values in R. Unfortunately, I was not able to calculate the point of inflection of the curve where the equivalence point is located.
Do you have any ideas on how I can do this?

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 1))

vtit <- c(7.05, 9.00, 11.10, 13.00, 15.00, 17.00, 18.05, 18.95, 20.00, 21.00,
          21.95, 23.05, 24.00, 25.05, 26.00, 28.10, 30.00, 33.05, 36.10, 39.05,
          41.10, 42.10, 42.55, 43.15, 44.99)
vtit. <- vtit - 7.05

pH <- c(2.99, 3.48, 3.82, 4.02, 4.18, 4.30, 4.37, 4.42, 4.45, 4.51, 4.57, 4.64,
        4.67, 4.74, 4.79, 4.86, 4.99, 5.18, 5.42, 5.77, 6.33, 9.01, 10.62,
        11.06, 11.39)

plot(vtit., pH, type="o", lwd=2, main="Titration of acetic acid with 0.86M NaOH",
     cex.main=0.8, xlab=expression(italic(V[NaOH])), ylab=expression(pH))

model <- lm(pH ~ poly(vtit.,17))
pHcurve <- predict(model)
lines(vtit., pHcurve, col='green', lwd=2)

abline(v=34.9, lty=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to try the `approx()` function in order to attempt a reasonable smoothing of the curve.  In the code below I am using 200 points, you may want to try increasing or decreasing this value to see how the results may change.
For this example this method works reasonably well,

```
plot(vtit., pH, type="o", lwd=2, main="Titration of acetic acid with 0.86M NaOH",
     cex.main=0.8, xlab=expression(italic(V[NaOH])), ylab=expression(pH))

#use the approx function
#plot(approx(vtit., pH, n=200))
app<-approx(vtit., pH, n=200)

#calculate the slope
slope <- (app$y-lag(app$y))/(app$x-lag(app$x))     
#find the titration point with max slope
equ_pt <- app$x[which.max(slope)]

#plot initial estimate aganist found point
abline(v=34.9, lty=2)
abline(v=equ_pt, lty=2, col="red")
```

Here is the original chart with the initial estimate and the current estimate in red.

[image]